# Problems with designing a Key/Value database schema

Tags: mysql, sql, cassandra, nosql

I'm Trying to design a Key/Value NOSql Database using Cassanda.
Starting from a relational Database for a little social network i want to make an "equivalent" schema using a NOSql database model.

The relational database have 3 tables and look like this:

```
     -------------
     | User      |
     -------------
     |id         |
     |name       |
     |bday       |
     |...        |
     -------------

     -------------
     | Statut    |
     -------------
     |Userid     |
     |Statutid   |
     |text       |
     |timestamp  |
     |...        |
     -------------

     -------------
     | Comment   |
     -------------
     |User1id    |
     |User2id    |
     |text       |
     |timestamp  |
     |......     |
     -------------
```

When crating the keyspace i get confused about haw many column family should i create:

- a column family for every table.
- only one column family that represent a user with his all his status and comments (in form of sets).

What is the best solution, with the minimum of data redundancy and avoiding joins.

Comment: More importantly, what are some of the queries that you need to have answered? If you add some sample queries, it will be easier to map your relational tables to CQL3 tables.

Comment: Your schema definition and use case in mysql will help.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB would be the best database to model this in if you want to reduce redundancy and avoiding joins.

Keep in mind using the collection `SET` data type.
[Straight from the docs](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations), **Collection values may not be larger than 64KB.**
So, using the `SET` will potentially give you problems depending what you are storing into it.

In Cassandra you can create this using 3 column families.

```
DROP KEYSPACE your_keyspace ;
CREATE KEYSPACE your_keyspace
  WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};

USE your_keyspace;


CREATE TABLE user(
  id TIMEUUID PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  bday TEXT,
  ...
);


CREATE TABLE user_statut(
  id TIMEUUID,
  userid TIMEUUID,
  body TEXT,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY(userid, id)
);


CREATE TABLE user_comment(
  id TIMEUUID,
  user1id TIMEUUID,
  user2id TIMEUUID,
  body TEXT,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY(user1id, user2id, id)
);
```

But of course this would require you to make 3 different queries to join all the data. But this depends on whatever queries you end up using.